# How to make MacPorts reinstall requested ports from a different boot drive?

Tags: macos, macports, migration

I recently changed workstations and went from OSx 10.7.5 to OSX 10.11! ***Yay!***

I have a lot of installation to do. ***Nuts....*** (But worth it!)

I have temporarily mounted my old workstation's hard drive to copy over important files. Since I have a different OS, a different version of XCode (and command line tools), and a different version of MacPorts, I'd rather do a fresh install of all my requested ports rather than semi-blindly copy stuff over from the old drive.

MacPorts has a great Migration guide ([link](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration)) that shows how to create a list of all installed ports, then reinstall them once software has been upgraded — but that's for upgrading on the same boot drive. My new drive has no installed ports because I just installed MacPorts.

**Is there a way to list requested ports on the old hard drive in order to upgrade them on my new drive?**

Comment: Perhaps the old workstation's MacPorts left a file on the old hard drive that tells what ports were installed and/or requested?

Comment: As explained in the migration guide, the installed ports list should be made from the starting version of MacOS X and MacPorts.

Comment: @danielAzuelos: Is there a way to run that version of MacPorts, then, from a different boot drive? (I don't even know where that executable would be.)

Comment: Does your old installation have this file - `/opt/local/var/macports/registry/registry.db`? You could build a requested list from this `sqlite3` database?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think you want the results of `port -qv installed` to restore your installation but I'll show you how to produce both files.

Mount the old hard drive and copy this file into a folder in your home folder- `/opt/local/var/macports/registry/registry.db`. Now navigate to that folder.

To produce the `requested.txt` file:

```
sqlite3 registry.db 'select name, requested from ports' |
awk -F '|' '{ if ( $2 == 1 ) print $1 }' >requested.txt
```

To produce the `myports.txt` file:

```
sqlite3 registry.db \
'select name,  version, revision, state, os_platform, os_major, archs, date from ports' |
sort |
awk -F'|' '{ if ( $4 == "installed") {act="(active)"} else {act=""} } 
{ cmd = "date -r" $8 " +%Y-%m-%dT%T%z"; cmd | getline mydate; close(cmd) }
{ printf ("%s @%s_%s %s platform=%s %s archs=%s date=%s\n",
    $1, $2, $3, act,$5, $6, $7, mydate)
}' >myports.txt
```

Comment: I get an error from awk: 
`non-terminated string %s @%s_%s ... at source line 3
 context is
  >>>  <<< 
awk: giving up`
Do you think there is a mistake in the awk code?

Comment: Yes, problems with quoting. The edit should fix it.